# How I make an output logic signal a real output pin?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I am trying to take this signal :
  signal Fx3_bridge : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);

To this output port:
Fx3_A        : out   std_logic;

I also want to discard the less significant bit of my logic vector.

Answer (score 1):

A `std_logic_vector` is an array. Your `std_logic_vector`

```
signal Fx3_bridge : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
```

has two elements - 1 and 0. You index arrays in VHDL using brackets, so the most significant bit (strictly speaking: the *left hand element*) is

```
Fx3_bridge(1)
```

So, you want something like:

```
Fx3_A <= Fx3_bridge(1);
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.2 Character set. Those are left and right parentheses and not left and right square or curly brackets. An indexed name (8.4) uses parentheses.

Comment: @user1155120 In British English, they're brackets.

Comment: Entomology shows parentheses are used as defined in the Cambridge dictionary, commonly used in IEEE and ISO/IEC standards.

Comment: It's often a good practice to not hard code the bit number, when possible, and in this case to use `Fx3_bridge(Fx3_bridge'high)` to keep its highest bit, even if the size changes later...